# For ら り る れ ろ, is the tongue blade ever in use?

Tags: pronunciation

I’m new to learning Japanese, and I am currently practicing on how to properly pronounce ら り る れ ろ. I have been told that you use your tongue tip to flick the roof of your mouth. I am able to produce the sound and people have told me it sounds good, but I feel like I am not using the tip of my tongue as told. I feel like I am using the blade of my tongue instead. To be really really honest, I feel like I am using the tip AND the blade of my tongue if that makes sense. I just want to ask if this is normal or if I should work on fixing this and start only using the tip of my tongue and not the blade at all. Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pronounce the Japanese "r"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/how-do-you-pronounce-the-japanese-r)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways is simply to listen to native speakers making these sounds and then mimic them. A very helpful technique is to record yourself making the sounds so that you can listen back and compare your attempts to the native speakers' versions.

- ら　https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E3%82%89/#ja
- り　https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E3%82%8A/#ja
- る　https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E3%82%8B/#ja
- れ　https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E3%82%8C/#ja
- ろ　https://ja.forvo.com/word/%E3%82%8D/#ja

Comment: I agree with kandyman. If I may add, I think Japanese have different pronunciations of their ら行. Some pronounce it like 75% American English L and 25% American English R, others make a 90%-10% mix, if you consider R and L to be at opposite sides of the spectrum.